# output of unix command in chef recipe

Tags: ruby, unix, chef-infra

I have an `execute` command in a chef recipe, and I'd like to set the `cwd` property as the output of a unix command.

```ruby
execute 'run dynamically generated install file' do
    command 'make install'
    cwd '' # would like the output of `ls -Adrt /tmp/unixODBC.* | tail -n 1`
end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so finally at a keyboard and can write this out in full.

The literal translation of what you have there would be:

```
execute 'run dynamically generated install file' do
    command 'make install'
    cwd lazy { shell_out!('ls -Adrt /tmp/unixODBC.* | tail -n 1').stdout.strip }
end
```

However that is going to be much slower than needed and more failure prone so I would recommend writing it in Ruby instead:

```
execute 'run dynamically generated install file' do
    command 'make install'
    cwd lazy { Dir['/tmp/unixODBC.*'].first }
end
```

This avoids having to spawn a bunch of processes and instead just does the same (I think) logic directly.

Comment: Beautiful. I ended up using `cwd lazy { Dir['/tmp/unixODBC.*'].sort_by{ |f| File.mtime(f) }.last + '/unixODBC-2.3.0' }`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it just like this:

```
execute 'run dynamically generated install file' do
    command 'make install'
    cwd `ls -Adrt /tmp/unixODBC.* | tail -n 1`
end
```

Comment: Easy enough.  Thanks @eiko

Comment: Don't do that. You're messing with ruby code within chef resource. That could fail in a wide number of way.

Comment: This is very much not recommended, both because Ruby's command execution is incredibly error prone and because this has no error handling of something fails

Comment: @Tensibai Agreed, this is not a safe way to do this.

Comment: @coderanger admittedly, i'm here as someone who knows ruby well, not someone who knows chef well. thanks for letting me know- i'm researching better implementations and will update my answer if someone else doesn't beat me to it!

Comment: Aww, I though I had post an answer before leaving work, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like it's out of the scope of an `execute` block.

Maybe just use a `ruby_block`?

```
ruby_block 'run dynamically generated install file' do
    require 'mixlib/shellout'
    block do
        cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('make install')
        cmd.run_command
        cwd = cmd.stdout
        # Do more stuff with cwd...
    end
end
```

Comment: I should add that `execute` is only good for commands you don't have to interact with very heavily.

Comment: This would also be incorrect in most cases, or at least overkill. Also never use the class directly, use the shell_out method wrapper to get some common Chef-y behaviors.